# AngularJS $http.post removing attributes

Tags: angularjs

When I do a `$http.post` in AngularJS with a object like:

```
{  name: '232', id: '3434', $type: "API.Models.Fields.ValuesList, API" }
```

with the signature:

```
$http.post('api/records', model);
```

the `$type` attribute is removed everytime on the chrome traffic listener no matter the value.

Is there some secret $ remover ;) ?

**UPDATE: ANGULAR >= 1.3 NOW DOES NOT REMOVE THE $ ATTRS.**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, Angular strips dollar-prefixed properties when sending data over `$http` service.

$http service serialises objects to JSON string using `angular.toJson` method. This method strips
properties with leading $ characters because angular uses this notation internally (e.g. instance method `$save` is available on all `ngResource` objects).

Quick workaround is to stringify the data manually (using JSON.stringify), before passing it on to `$http`:

```js
$http.post('/api/path', JSON.stringify(model));
```

Comment: Thanks Stewie.  Odd that it strips them but i guess that makes sense given its native properties are usually prefixed with $

Comment: What if we need to send a regular expression or something? JSON.stringify doesn't allow that..

Comment: @Devin JSON format does not allow for RegExp, Function, Date, or even undefined. The only types allowed are number, object, array, true, false, null. See http://json.org/ for the full specification.

Comment: To be clear, you can still *serialize* these other types into strings, just be sure to be consistent and maintain serialization/deserialization functionality in parity on client/server.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments, but there is an ongoing confusion among many (most?) JS devs that JSON is the same as POJO. POJO is not limited in what it can contain, and it does not need strings (double quote strings, at that!) for property keys. JSON does.

Comment: FYI - This is not a problem w/ 1.3